# redirect url from pagination using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I want to redirect a link like this

```
http://www.domain.yyy/newpiratefiles/category.php?cat=dorama&page=2
```

to

```
http://www.domain.yyy/newpiratefiles/category/dorama&page=2
```

so, I can still call `page` to generate my pagination. I try like this but now working

```
RewriteRule ^category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    category.php?cat=$1&page=$2   [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're maintaining a `htaccess` file, please check:

- the htaccess file is inside `newpiratefiles` directory
- the server has the `AllowOverride` set to a not-None value
- there aren't other conflicting rules up the rule chain which might override the behaviour

apart from the above, in your rewrite, you are referencing `page=$2`, but the pattern does not have a 2nd matched group in it. Try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([\w-]+)/?$ category.php?cat=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}   [NC,L]
```

and your pagination will go like:

```
http://www.domain.yyy/newpiratefiles/category/dorama?page=2
```

notice the `?` instead of `&` in above URL